# Truffle Drizzle error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, truffle, drizzle

**Expected:**

After running the app, the user should see a `"Loading Drizzle..."` msg in the browser then soon followed by `"Drizzle is ready"`.

**Results:**

The app stays stuck on `"Loading Drizzle..."` and there is an error in the chrome console:

Error

> uncaught at root at root
>
> at contractsSaga
>
> at takeEvery
>
> at addContract
>
> at instantiateContract
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

I'm following this tutorial here: https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-drizzle-and-react

And I'm at the current section:

## Replace the render method

```
render() {
  if (this.state.loading) return "Loading Drizzle...";
  return <div className="App">Drizzle is ready</div>;
}
```

I've done that in my app, and expected to see the "Drizzle is ready" message, but instead got the error above.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/leongaban/truffle_drizzle_test

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No contracts are deployed to your ganache network, which is why that error is occurring.

In the root of your folder, make sure you run `truffle migrate` after `truffle compile`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, even after deploying the contracts correctly to my ganache network. The reason it didn't work for me was that I had MetaMask active on my Chrome Browser. I was not even logged in, but still it appears that the dapp was looking for the contract on the wrong network. When I open the site with Incognito Mode / completely disabled MetaMask, it works!

This is something the tutorial points out, but I guess it's easy to not take seriously:

> Note: Make sure to use an incognito window if you already have
>   MetaMask installed (or disable MetaMask for now). Otherwise, the app
>   will try to use the network specified in MetaMask rather than the
>   development network under localhost:8545.

Answer (score 0):

`truffle migrate` will deploy your contract onto your blockchain network, and then output a file `build/contracts/YourContract.json` which contains info about your contract.  For example, it contains the ABI for your contract and the address that your contract was deployed at.

Your JavaScript probably imports that JSON file in order to have the needed information to connect to your contract.  Therefore, be sure that the JS is importing the most up-to-date version of the JSON, otherwise it won't know which address to find your contract at, etc.